# How to get the name of Array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, httpresponse

Here is the response data got from interface:

```
[{"id": 7, "ip": "33333333", "name": "CPU1", "address": "22222222"}, {"id": 8, "ip": "33333333", "name": "CPU1", "address": "22222222"}, {"id": 9, "ip": "33333333", "name": "CPU1", "address": "22222222"}, {"id": 10, "ip": "33333333", "name": "CPU1", "address": "22222222"}]
```

I want to get the `"id"`, `"ip"`, `"name"`, `"CPU1"`, not their values.

How to get them?

Comment: `Object.keys(arr[0])`

Comment: Use `Object.keys`..May be in a loop...